# Add and remove classes when click on multiple divs using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am actually trying to add class (Selected) to the li when clicked and remove Class from neighbour li.

**Issue is it doesn't work when there is 2 ul, the below code only work on the 1st ul or when i click on the li of the second li, first li active gets removed**

```js
const menuLis = document.querySelectorAll("#top-nav > li");

for (let li of menuLis) {
  
  li.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // 1. Remove Class from All Lis
    for (let li of menuLis) {
      li.classList.remove('selected');
    }
    
    // 2. Add Class to Relevant Li
    this.classList.add('selected');
  });
  
}
```

```css
.selected{color:red}
```

```html
<ul id='top-nav'>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<ul id='top-nav'>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Ids have to be unique. Only one per page. Use a class and target that instead.

Comment: I have updated the above with class then also it doesn't work @Andy

Comment: @Andy I have updated the above with class then also it doesn't work

Comment: You shouldn't go back and edit your question with new information because it makes information in the answers addressing those issues redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a class, as well to separate handling for each ul for it to properly work:

```js
const menuUls = document.querySelectorAll('.top-nav');

for (const ul of menuUls) {
  const menuLis = ul.querySelectorAll('li');

  for (const li of menuLis) {
    li.addEventListener('click', function () {
      // 1. Remove Class from All Lis
      for (let li of menuLis) {
        li.classList.remove('selected');
      }

      // 2. Add Class to Relevant Li
      this.classList.add('selected');
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.selected{color:red}
```

```html
<ul class='top-nav'>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<ul class='top-nav'>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It doesnt work when i replace ul with div and li with label. Thank you

Comment: That's now what you're asking thought, you need to be specific for us to help you. Anyways if you replace `li` with `label` then you just need to update `querySelectorAll` to search `label` instead of `li`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not have two identical IDs on a page. Second, instead of applaying your logic on all the `li`s on the page, it should be per `url`, like so:

```js
const menus = [document.getElementById("top-nav"), document.getElementById("bottom-nav")]

for(let menu of menus){
  const lis = menu.querySelectorAll("li");
  for (let li of lis) {

    li.addEventListener("click", function(){
      // 1. Remove class from All lis Of this ul
      for (let li of lis) {
        li.classList.remove('selected');
      }

      // 2. Add Class to Relevant Li
      this.classList.add('selected');
    });

  }
}
```

```css
.selected{color:red}
```

```html
<ul id='top-nav'>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<ul id='bottom-nav'>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the element's `siblings`, and remove the `selected` class.

```js
const menuLis = document.querySelectorAll(".top-nav > li");

for (let li of menuLis) {
  
  li.addEventListener("click", function(){
    for (let sibling of this.parentNode.children) {
        sibling.classList.remove('selected');
    }
    this.classList.add('selected');
  });
  
}
```

```css
.selected{color:red}
```

```html
<section>
  <section>
    <div>
      <ul class='top-nav'>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <ul class='top-nav'>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Code work perfectly, but actually both are not the near each ul. ul are actually wrapped in a div and sections
<div>
<section>
<ul class='top-nav'>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
</div>
</section>
<div>

<ul class='top-nav'>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
</section>
</div>

Comment: @AnthonyDavid, it doesn't matter if they're wrapped, you can see in the updated example it should and will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Ids must be unique - one per page only, so you should use a class instead.

Another thing to think about is: on every click you're adding new listeners to *all* the list items which might be okay for a small example but might prove inefficient at scale.

An alternative method would be to use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) - attach *one* listener to each parent element, the list item, and check the information on the event target to update its list items.

```js
const menus = document.querySelectorAll('.top-nav');

menus.forEach(menu => {
  menu.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
});

function handleClick(e) {

  const { nodeName, parentNode } = e.target;

  // If the clicked element is a list item
  if (nodeName === 'LI') {

    // Find all the list items of the current list
    const items = parentNode.querySelectorAll('li')

    // Remove the class from each, and then add the
    // class to the element that was clicked
    items.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('selected'));
    e.target.classList.add('selected');

  }

}
```

```css
.selected { color:red; }
li:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<ul class="top-nav">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

<ul class="top-nav">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)